# One line command for getting the number of dnf updates

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora, dnf

I am trying to get the number of updates from the dnf without using sudo privilages. I guess `dnf check-update` is the first starting point but any idea how can I do this. It's important the solution is 1 line.

Is something like this possible ?

Comment: Does "updated package pulls in new dependency that you did not have installed before" count as 1 or 2 updates?

Comment: Is this for interactive use our would you rather have something like a scripting API for dnf?

Comment: Why do you insist the commabd would be one line? You could always just create a single script that will run few commands, and you'll run the script in one command line, so I see no reason to limit the answers.

Comment: @MarcusMüller "updated package pulls in new dependency that you did not have installed before" It doesn't much matter for me. The easier method would be fine. So I guess you can take it as 1.

Comment: @MarcusMüller "Is this for interactive use our would you rather have something like a scripting API for dnf?" I would say interactive, I will just type in terminal...

Comment: @aviro I have seen written scripts and some of them needs sudo privilages added in `sudoers`. I am just thinking simple and want to implement it simple. Without needing add `dnf` to `sudoers` or without writing a script. The length of the command is also not important.

Comment: Sudo/privileges and length of script are completely independent, so let's not conflate them! You can do a one-liner, something like `dnf check-update| grep some pattern | wc -l` but to me it's not obvious that would be easier or prettier than putting that into a script

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am trying to implement it in polybar. thats kind of why I am avoiding scripts. I know you can add scripts to polybar but adding a one-line command seems more simpler than adding a script.

Comment: I have noticed that `dnf check-update| grep updates | wc -l` seems to be working

Comment: @Neptune so, you're not actually going to type them if you're to use these commands in polybar…

Comment: @MarcusMüller well technically I am just copy pasting the command to some variable in polybar. So for me it seems the same...

Comment: @Neptune just a couple of notes: usually, adding something to a script and giving the script to another tool (as you want to do with polybar) is both easier and simpler to get to work. A script is just one command, whereas a one-liner can be several. The "script" is nothing but a text file containing the command(s). Next, "one-liners" can be very, very long and complicated. I have one-liners in my bash history that are almost three thousand characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this works:

```
dnf check-update| grep -Ec ' updates$'
```

since in each upgrade line there's a word `updates` at the end.

Comment: On RHEL8 the lines end with the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Quietly check the updates and count the packages, i.e. lines starting with text:

`dnf check-update -q|grep -c ^[a-z0-9]`